# Remove lines based upon string

Tags: powershell, lines

I have an error log file from which want to copy all lines that DON'T match a set error strings. So basically I am building up a separate file of unrecognised errors.

I define all the know error types

```
# Define all the error types that we need to search on 
$error_1 = "Start Date must be between 1995 and 9999"
$error_2 = "SYSTEM.CONTACT_TYPE"
$error_3 = "DuplicateExternalSystemIdException"
$error_4 = "From date after To date in address"
$error_5 = "Missing coded entry  for provider type category record"
```

and this is what I am doing to read in the file

```
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $error_1 } |
    Out-File $path\uncategorised_errors.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $error_2 } |
    Out-File $path\uncategorised_errors.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $error_3 } |
    Out-File $path\uncategorised_errors.log
```

My input file is like this:

```
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 ExternalSystemId cannot be the same as an existing provider
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 DuplicateExternalSystemIdException
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 DuplicateExternalSystemIdException
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 SYSTEM.CONTACT_TYPE
```

and my out is exactly the same when I should have only 3 lines:

```
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 ExternalSystemId cannot be the same as an existing provider
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
15 Jul 2016 20:02:11,340 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $error_1 -and $_ -notmatch $error_2 -and $_ -notmatch $error_3 -and $_ -notmatch $error_4 -and $_ -notmatch $error_5} | Out-File $path\uncategorised_errors.log
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I did just get this workbut your answer is more elegant and is just a one liner.
    $result = Get-Content $path\temp_report.log
$result | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch [regex]::escape($error_1)} | Set-Content $path\uncategorised_errors.log

Answer (score 1):

Make the known errors an array, use `Select-String`

```
$errors=@(
    "Start Date must be between 1995 and 9999",
    "SYSTEM.CONTACT_TYPE",
    "DuplicateExternalSystemIdException",
    "From date after To date in address",
    "Missing coded entry  for provider type category record"
)

Select-String -Path D:\log.txt -NotMatch -Pattern $errors
```

Comment: I'd add `-SimpleMatch` to avoid unexpected results from special characters in the filter strings.