# Overwriting output file?

Tags: file, powershell, append

I am extracting some errors from a log file into a separate file.

The errors that I am searching for are defined in a little block:

```
# Define all the error types that we need to search on
$error_6  = "Missing coded entry in table for provider sector category record"
$error_7  = "not a well-formed email address"
$error_8  = "Org Id must not contain invalid characters"
$error_9  = "Missing sub type code for provider type category record"
$error_10 = "Provider sub type"
```

I then read in the source log file and strip out the matching lines.

Weirdly, if I dump them into separate files I get the correct number of lines in each file, but if I use the same file I only get one line. I thought that it would append to the file.

This doesn't work (only one line of output):

```
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_6 } |   Set-Content $path\known_errors.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_7 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_8 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_9 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_10 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors.log
```

Works (16 lines of output in total):

```
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_6 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors_6.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_7 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors_7.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_8 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors_8.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_9 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors_9.log
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match $error_10 } | Set-Content $path\known_errors_10.log
```

Comment: You do realize that by changing "not match" to "match" the answers to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38405279/1630171) work for this too, don't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Set-Content` *always* creates a new file.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849828.aspx

> **Set-Content**
>   Writes or replaces the content in an item with new content.

You need to use `Add-Content` to add data to an existing file.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849859.aspx

> **Add-Content**
>   Adds content to the specified items, such as adding words
>   to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use:

```
(Get-Content $path\temp_report.log) | Where-Object { $_ -match  $error_6 } |  out-file $path\known_errors.log -Append
```